# Oracle. JPA 2.1 "Missing IN or OUT parameter" when parameter is null

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I try to call oracle stored procedure with null parameter. And get error 
"java.sql.sqlexception missing in or out parameter at index..."

Named stored procedure declaration

```
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "testDeal",
    procedureName = "pkg_api.test_deal",
    parameters = {
       @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_id_in", type = Integer.class),
       @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "p_id_out", type = Integer.class)
    }
    ),
```

Call

```
   StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("testDeal");
    query.setParameter("p_id_in",null);
    query.execute();
```

PL/SQL

```
  procedure test_deal(p_id_in      in  number default null,
                     p_id_out     out  number) is
  begin
    p_id_out:= coalesce(p_id_in,666);  
  end;
```

If I execute procedure with not null parameter, it works fine.

I use:

Ojdbc7 12.1.0.2

Hibernate-jpa-2.1

Spring 4.1.1

Oracle version 12.1.0.2

Comment: Did you try  `setNull()`  in case of `null` assignment. It works with `JDBC`, not sure w.r.t `JPA`

Comment: Thak you, but unfortunately javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery  has not method set null

Comment: @pleshakoffav Did you managed to find a solution for this ?

Comment: No, I used JDBC for stored procedure call